# Como capturar el Index en el clic de una matriz de botones creada dinámicamente

Tags: c#, vb.net, net

Estoy creando una grilla de botones de forma dinámica y no estoy pudiendo capturar el index en el evento clik. 
Estoy usando este trozo de código:

```
private void InitTablero()
    {
        Button boton = new Button();
        int cont = 1;

        int[,] matriz = new int[Tabla.RowCount, Tabla.ColumnCount];

        for (int f = 0; f < Tabla.RowCount; f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < Tabla.ColumnCount; c++)
            {
                boton = new Button();
                boton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                boton.Text = (cont).ToString();
                cont+=1;
                boton.BackColor = Color.White;
                boton.Click += new EventHandler(Onb2Click);
                boton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;                    
                boton.Margin = Padding.Empty;                 
                Tabla.Controls.Add(boton, c, f);
            }
        }

    }

    void Onb2Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       // Console.WriteLine(sender.index);

    }
```

Estoy creando una grilla de botones de forma dinámica y no estoy pudiendo capturar el index en el evento clik. 
Estoy usando este trozo de código:

Comment: Queres saber que boton presionaron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo en Visual Basic uso DirectCast, que me permite saber a que botón le di clic sin importar que atributos tenga el botón:

```
Dim btn As button = DirectCast(sender, button)
```

En C# creo que va así (no programo en C# solo se Python y VB así que disculpa cualquier error de sintaxis jejejeje)

```
button btn = (button)sender; 


Checa un ejemplo en de algo que estoy trabajando:

Public btnList As New List(Of ucImgUser) From {}

Private Sub BtnAddColaborador_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddColaborador.Click Dim ucImgUser = New ucImgUser btnList.Add(ucImgUser) btnList.Item(i).Name = "ucImgUser" & i AddHandler btnList.Item(i).boton1.Click, AddressOf ClickColaboradores end sub

Public Sub ClickColaboradores(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Dim btn As button= DirectCast(sender, button) end sub
```

en C#:

```
public List<ucImgUser> btnList = new List<ucImgUser>() { };

private void BtnAddColaborador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ucImgUser = new ucImgUser();
    btnList.Add(ucImgUser);
    btnList.Item[i].Name = "ucImgUser" + i;
    btnList.Item[i].boton1.Click += ClickColaboradores;
}

public void ClickColaboradores(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button btn = (button)sender;
...
...
...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Para saber que boton presionaron, deberias darle un nombre al boton, luego en el evento click le haces un unboxing al object que trae el evento, usando el `as` si no esta bien el unboxing la app no lanzara excepcion y te dara null si no se convirtio bien el object a Button. Luego podras acceder a sus propiedades y saber que boton fue presionado.

```
 private void InitTablero()
    {
        int cont = 1;
        Button boton = new Button();
        //tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = Padding.Empty;

        int[,] matriz = new int[tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount, tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount];

        for (int f = 0; f < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; c++)
            {

            boton = new Button();
            boton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            boton.Text = (cont).ToString();
            cont+=1;
            boton.Name = cont.ToString();
            boton.BackColor = Color.White;
            boton.Click += new EventHandler(Onb2Click);
            boton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;                    
            boton.Margin = Padding.Empty;                 
            Tabla.Controls.Add(boton, c, f);

            }
        }

    }
    void Onb2Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if(button != null)
        {
          string name = button.Name; // con el nombre que le diste al crear el boton sabras que boton presionaron.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sos un groso Ramiro !! me gustaría tenerte en mi equipo!! gracias